# Navigate google map screen to updated marker position

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular2-services

I am using AGM(angular google map) for map stuff. I have put a getCurrentLocation button, which returns me latitude and longitude of current location. I am able to update the marker to that place but my maps is not navigating to that specific location. Here is my sample code.

```
getCurrentLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((response) => {
            this.setPosition(response);
        }, function () {
            alert("Unable to get the GPS location");
        }, { maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    };
}
```

and here is my setPosition method

```
setPosition(position: Position) {
    this.marker.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.marker.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    //What to do here to move screen to this marker position
}
```

Here is my screen after updating the marker. Marker is lost. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. Basically problem was i was mapping 'agm-marker' and 'agm-map' [latitude] and [longitude] with different variables. So once i started to map it with same variables it started to worked fine.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="signageRequest.gpsXcoordinate" [clickableIcons]="gpsXcoordinateStatus.readonly" [mapDraggable]="!gpsXcoordinateStatus.readonly"
[longitude]="signageRequest.gpsYcoordinate" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]=false [zoomControl]=false (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)"
    [usePanning]="true">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="signageRequest.gpsXcoordinate" [longitude]="signageRequest.gpsYcoordinate" [markerDraggable]="false"
            (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(marker, $event)"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: This is not working in my case. My code:  <agm-map (mapReady)="mapReady($event)" [usePanning]="true" [styles]="styles" [latitude]="sellerDetails.latitude" [longitude]="sellerDetails.longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
                    <agm-marker
                      [latitude]="sellerDetails.latitude"
                      [longitude]="sellerDetails.longitude"
                      doRebuildAll="true"
                      [iconUrl]="markerIcon">
                    </agm-marker>
                  </agm-map>

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the latitude and longitude to the `agm-map` component to make the map center itself around that coordinate.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

The example above centers the map around the marker.

From the [API docs](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmMap.html):

- `latitude`: The latitude that defines the center of the map.
- `longitude`: The longitude that defines the center of the map.

Comment: That is already mapped. I need to call agmMap.triggerResize()
 method in my opinion. But i do't know how to get hold of agmMap object in my ts class. It's always null.

Comment: You can also apply `usePanning` on the `agm-map`. That causes the map to center around the provided latitude and longitude whenever one of the two changes. (`<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [usePanning]="true">`)

Comment: Thanks for the response i have used that property. It's description is telling the same you are mentioning but it is't working. I am updating the model but it is not working

Comment: Works fine in an application I'm currently working on. Could you show the code of your view file (the file where you put `<agm-map>` etc) or replicate the issue in a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: Thanks @kaj. I was able to figure out the problem. Basically problem was i was mapping 'agm-marker' and 'agm-map' with different variables. So once i started to map it with same it worked fine. Please checkout the answer, i am putting now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little too late. I had the same problem.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
<agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
```

Your .ts:

```
latitude: number = 21.4949494;
longitude: number = 101.49834;
```

Those variables ***must be a number not a string.*** Use parseFloat to solve that.